# Failed to http Connect in Android

Tags: java, android, emulation, httpconnection

Well this code works fine in java but when i started to run it on Android 4.0 emulator it crashes. While Debugging i noticed that it crushed on httpConn.connect(); line

```
  public class GetStringFromUrl {
public static String getString(String urlPageAdress) throws Exception
{

    URL url = new URL(urlPageAdress);
     HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
      httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
     httpConn.connect(); //crashes on this line dunno know why

     InputStream in = null;

     if (httpConn.getContentEncoding() != null && httpConn.getContentEncoding().toString().contains("gzip")) {
     in = new GZIPInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream());
      } else {
      in = httpConn.getInputStream();
    }
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
     ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);
     int read = 0;
      int bufSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
     while (true) {
      read = bis.read(buffer);
      if (read == -1) {
    break;
      }
     baf.append(buffer, 0, read);



     }
      String body = new String(baf.toByteArray());
    return body;
} }
```

method is used in Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
ToggleButton  toogleButton;
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "ru.kazartsevaa.table.MESSAGE";
int upDown;
int SpinnerCount;
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    upDown=0;


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

public void onClick(View v) throws Exception 
    {   System.out.print(SpinnerCount);
    //  if(upDown==0) //0 - вылет 1 прилет
        //{
            switch (v.getId()) 
            {
                    case R.id.UpDownButton:
                    {
                        //toogleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.UpDownButton);
                    //  toogleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                    }
                    case R.id.SheremetievoButton:
                    {
                        Spinner SherSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SheremetievoSpinner);

```
                    String SpinnerCount= SherSpinner.getItemAtPosition(SherSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                    System.out.print(SpinnerCount);
                    new Thread(){ public void run() { 
                        try {
                            String body = GetStringFromUrl.getString("www.xyz.com");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        } }.start();

                        int crowd;






                }

        }
```

Note: After changing to new thread it stopped crushing but still writes

Comment: make sure that you didn't forget to put internet permission to the manifest file

Comment: thnx - never knew about that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this in the main thread? Should work if you execute this in a separate thread.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
            new Thread(){
                    public void run() {
                        GetStringFromUrl.getString("www.xyz.com");                      
                    }
            }.start();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: well the method is run in MainActivity after onClick  (After i push the button)

Comment: Try using a thread inside onClick

 new Thread(){
   public void run() {
    INSERT YOUR CODE FOR FUNCTION HERE
   }
 }.start();

Comment: No you cannot launch it inside directly inside activity, since time consuming operations like connecting to network should be done in separate thread. Edited answer for your understanding.

Comment: Thnx well it helped with addition to manifest - but still returns null((( And debugger doesn't even go into method((

Comment: What is the issue now? Is it throwing some exception?

Comment: Yeah !!!!!! Fk Yeah thnx !!! It worked !! The thing is it launched  the new thread after on click finished